# Replication TempDB size

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I currently have replication setup across 2 MS SQL Servers (both running 2008 r2).

On the subscriber, my tempdb is filling to a ridiculous rate quickly, circa 28gb within an hour. I understand that tempdb needs to be used in order to store transactions in progress but surely this should shrink back down after?

I have also got a 35Gb Log file for the replication, which I dont seem to be able to shrink either.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help, right click on `TempDb` database and choose `Properties` in `Options` tab check the `RecoveryModel` and change it to `Simple` if it is something else. If you change that then `Shrink` your db.

TempDb will get back to it's original size when you restart SQL Server, but there are methods to shrink it without restarting.

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
go
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
GO
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (TEMPDEV,1024) --- New file size in MB
GO
```

So you can define a scheduled job to shrink it on regular basis

Comment: I have done exactly that but tempdb regrows within a few hours.